# Every bounded monotone sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove:

> If a sequence is monotone and bounded then it converges.

My idea is: Assume $a_n$ is monotone and not converges and then show that it is not bounded. But: my problem is that I fail to prove it is not bounded. Please can you help me?

I found a different proof in a book but I want to know if my proof can work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a bounded, monotone sequence in $\Bbb R$; without loss of generality assume that the sequence is non-decreasing. To prove that it converges, at some point you’re going to have to use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete: the theorem is not true in $\Bbb Q$. The most straightforward way to use completeness is simply to let $a=\sup\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, which exists by completeness because the sequence is bounded, and show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to a$. I don’t see any way to carry out your idea without essentially incorporating this argument as part of it, and if you do that, you’re just needlessly complicating things.

Answer (score 35):

Without loss of generality assume that $(a_n)$ is increasing and bounded above (the other case is similar) then the set
$$A=\{a_n\;|\; n\in\mathbb N\}$$
has a supremum $s=\sup A$ and we know by the characterization of this supremum:
$$\forall \epsilon>0,\; \exists a_p\in A \;|\; s-\epsilon\le a_p\le s$$
but since $(a_n)$ is increasing then
$$\forall \epsilon>0,\; \exists p\in\mathbb N, \forall n\ge p \;|\; s-\epsilon\le a_p\le a_n\le s$$
which means that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$.

Comment: Is that little vertical line $\;\mid\;$ supposed to mean "s.t.=such that" , or what? I've never seen that.

Comment: Yes it means such that and I think it's well known.

Comment: Never saw it...anyway, +1 .

Comment: @Don: It's well known with that meaning in set builder notation, of course ... but is not a usual choice of punctuation to use together with quantifiers.

Comment: This is probably the "different proof" the OP wrote about already having seen.

Comment: I think $s-\epsilon \le a_p \le s$ should be $s-\epsilon <a_p \le s$ to make the last line translate to the definition of convergence and this also true for supremum definition I think

Comment: Also you should state it is bounded below by the first element.

Answer (score 7):

Note that this statement would not be true if we were working exclusively with rational numbers, because a monotone and bounded sequence of rational numbers does not necessarily have a rational limit. So you will have to use a special property of the reals here. In which way that property was formulated in your class we do not know.

Answer (score 2):

The original post asks: *My idea is: Assume $a_n$ is monotone and not converges and then show that it is not bounded. But: my problem is that I fail to prove it is not bounded. Please can you help me?*

If you want to prove the statement, *if a sequence is monotone and bounded then it converges*, the logically equivalent contrapositive would be, *if a sequence is divergent then either it is not monotone or it is not bounded*. So, your idea would only get you halfway there. You would also need to prove that divergent bounded sequences cannot be monotone.

To the question asked though, you are seeking a *direct* proof of monotone and divergent $\implies$ unbounded. This will be a bit awkward as divergent and unbounded are defined in the negative. Without loss of generality assume the sequence $(a_n)$ is divergent and increasing. A divergent sequence in the reals is not a Cauchy sequence, which means there is a small distance $\epsilon>0$ such that there is an infinite subsequence $(b_n)$ whose members are at least $\epsilon$ apart from each other. Then, since $(a_n)$ and hence $(b_n)$ are increasing, $b_n \ge b_0 + n  \epsilon$ grows without bound.