# Limit of a strictly increasing sequence bounded by strictly decreasing sequence is sandwiched between the sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

While reading [Mills' proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-06/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2.pdf) of the prime formula that's named after him, I believe the following statement is used:

> Let $a_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence and $b_n$ be a strictly decreasing sequence such that $a_n < b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $a =\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ exists and $a_n < a < b_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I attempted to give a more detailed proof of this step as an exercise.

---

***Proof***: Since $ a_n <b_n <b_0$, then  $a_n$ is strictly increasing and bounded from above, so it [converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/609041/695196). We denote the existing limit by $a$.

BWOC we assume that $a\le a_{m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We define $\varepsilon_a = a_{m+1} -a>0$. Since for *all* naturals $n>m+1$ we have $a_n >a_{m+1} > a$, we get  $$|a_n - a| = a_n -a \mathbin{\color{red}{>}}a_{m+1} -a = \varepsilon_a$$
which contradicts the existence of  $a$, so
we conclude that $a > a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Similarly, BWOC we assume $a \ge b_m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We define $\varepsilon_b = a - b_{m+1}>0$. Since for *all* naturals $n >m+1$ we have
$a \ge b_m>b_{m+1}>b_n >a_n$, we get

$$
|a_n -a| =a - a_n\mathbin{\color{red}{>}}a-b_{m+1} = \varepsilon_b
$$
which contradicts the existence of  $a$, so
we conclude that $a < b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

Although I believe the previous proof is valid, I didn't like that I had to separate the problem into several smaller proofs. So my question is

> Are there any alternative ways to prove the statement? Preferably without separating the proof into cases.

Any and all ideas are welcome. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I incorrectly used "monotone" to mean "strict increasing/decreasing". I've changed the writing in my question to correct this mistake.

Comment: As stated your theorem is false. A counter example is $a_n=0$ since then $a=0$ and so $a_n$ is equal to $a$, not strictly less than it. You need to require that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are strictly increasing/decreasing sequences.

Comment: My bad. For some reason I used "monotone" to mean "strict" in the question. The arguments I add work with this assumption, but I wrote it correctly in the title. I'll add an edit to correct this, thank you!

Comment: There are two things to prove: $\forall n\,(a_n<a)$ and $\forall n\,(a<b_n)$ so it's natural to need two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $a_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence, $b_n$ a strictly decreasing sequence, and $a_n<b_n$ for all $n$.

Note that $a_n$ is bounded by $b_0$ and $b_n$ by $a_0$.

By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the limit of $a_n$ equals $\sup(a_n)$. Denote this as $a$. For all $i$, $a_i<a_{i+1}\leq \sup(a_n) =a$.

For any positive integer $i,j$ we have that $a_i<a_{i+j}<b_{i+j}<b_{j}$. Therefore, for all $j$, $b_j$ is an upper bound for the sequence $a_n$, so by the definition of $\sup$, $b_j$ is at least $\sup(a_n)=a$.

Applying this to $b_{n+1}$ gives $a \leq b_{n+1}<b_n$ for all $n$. Putting this together with the above, for all $n$, $a_n<a<b_n$ as desired.